# ДСП — писать строчными или прописными?

Tags: аббревиатуры, прописная-строчная

Завис над аббревиатурой "дсп" (древесно-стружечная плита). Как нужно ее писать: строчными или прописными? По идее, это не имена собственные...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ДСП или ДСтП (официальная аббревиатура). Все аббревиатуры, где от начального слова осталась лишь одна буква (МГУ, ТРЦ, ООО и пр.) пишутся прописными буквами.

Comment: Но  - вуз..